# get the current UIKeyBoardType that is being used? Or capture when the UIKeyboardType has changed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikeyboardtype

In my app I do some searching in the background (NSOperationQueue) and once I am done and show the results in a UITableView on the main queue but the UIKeyboardType always gets reset.

How can I get the current UIKeyboardType once it is changed by the user?

i tried storing the type in a variable before the search but the textField that is doing the search is not returning the actual type of keyboard that is visible but rather the UIKeyboardType that is set to by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve my problem.  I checked to see what the last character was they typed in to the search field and determined the UIKeyboardType based on that:

```
if ([searchText length]>0) {
        NSRange nond = [[searchText substringFromIndex:[searchText length]-1] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
        if (NSNotFound == nond.location) {
            self.currentKeyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        } else {
            self.currentKeyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        }
    }
```

Then after the search completes I set the UIKeyboardType to this value.  It seems to me that by default my app was switching the keyboard back based on the default keyboard I had set for the UISearchBar text field.  This is working great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textField.keyboardType` and get the type of keyboard for a textField...

Comment: I did that but it does not make a difference - it always shows the default keyboard type: NSLog(@"keyboard type: %d", self.searchBar.keyboardType);

This always shows 0 no matter what type of keyboard I am using.

Comment: It's supposed that you can modify the type of keyboard shown by modifying this variable... Then, the reverse is true...

Comment: I have to capture what the current keyboard type is first so i can set it back after my search is done

Comment: I'm not following you... You have already set the keyboardType in the storyboard or so, don't you?

Comment: yes it is set by default BUT the user can change it, I need to capture what they changed it to

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me how the user can change the keyboardType?

Comment: easy, the little key button in the bottom left that let's you switch from numbers to letters, or the one above that that let's you select special characters

Comment: But then that is not a keyboardType change! The keyboard type remains being the same "all allowed", learn more here: http://shareourideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/iphone-keyboard-type.png

What you want is detect if the user changed the keyboard view to access numbers or symbols, but I'm sorry to tell you that as far as I know this is not possible with the standard API... Not sure why you need this, but, won't be better to just look what is left in the UITextField and then decide what to do?

Comment: it is a change, look at the link you sent - it says UI Keyboard Type in each on of those showing what each one is

Comment: Maybe you can see it better here (http://www.globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/xcode-keyboard-types.jpg), you can choice the keyboard predefined type, but you can't know the changes that are happening, and the user pressing the numbers option doesn't count as keyboardType change...

For what you are trying to do, you'll need to create a custom keyboard...

Why do you need this?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24925/discussion-between-slee-and-apascua)